# Use CSS3 perspective and transform to render image as 3d cube

Tags: php, html, css, imagemagick, css-transforms

I have been using PHP and ImageMagick for to generate a 3D preview of a canvas print (see image below).

[image]

There are options to change the edge type, depth, size etc which are AJAX calls to a PHP support file which re-renders the preview with new settings and I reload it into the DOM.

This is starting to overload our server when busy. So I thought I could do this in CSS3 and do all the preview rendering client-side instead.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature" alt="Nature">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  perspective: 500px;
  margin: 4em auto; 
  width: 37em;
}

.inner {
  transform: rotateY(40deg);
}

.inner div {
  width: 11em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.inner img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The problem I am having is wrapping the image around the edges like in the image above. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean do this in css3 with 6 images that cut from one picture by imageMagick ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a demo, with 2 elements holding the same image.

Just set the image origin on them accordingly to the dimension, and it will match.

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  background-size: 0px 0px;
  perspective: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: -40px 0px;
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting @vals but your right hand edge fails when I run the example code. Also with the perspective you have that edge would not be visible?

Comment: There was a mistake on the width of the front element, it must be 400 - 40. Corrected :-)